# An error occurred applying migrations, try applying them from the command line

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2019

I am on visual studio 2019 for mac running a blazor server app with .net core 3.1 and Individual Authentication (In-app) turned on.

When i go to register and enter new users details i am presented with the following error when clicking the apply migrations button

[image]

In the appsettings.json i have the following set.

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=Test; user=SA; password=P@55word; Trusted_Connection=False;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using CMUI.Areas.Identity;
using CMUI.Data;

namespace CMUI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The the SQL server i am running is 2019 mssql in docker using the following command

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=P@55word' -p 1433:1433 -d --name=mssqlserver2019  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

The database is working okay as i can perform crud actions via an webapi in another solution using the same connection string. Not sure if this is a mac thing or if i have missed something silly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the command line and navigating to the project root of the project that connects to that db, and then running `dotnet ef database update` which *should* run that migration and build your identity tables. Then fire the app up again and as long as it's connecting (which is looks like you are) you should be able to register users.

[Further reading on migrations here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) You may need to install the command line tools mentioned in this article.

I'm not familiar with VS for MacOS, but in the windows version you can go to Package Manager Console, make sure the default project in the console is set to your DB access project, and then run the command `update-database`. This might work for you as well.

Comment: Sadly this is not an option on a mac. I know there is an extension you can use called NuGet package management extensions that allows you to run commands but this appears to be broken as all i get is Method not found: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.get_JsonSerializer()